# Removing generic parameter from method signiture

Tags: c#, generics, backwards-compatibility, method-resolution-order

I have a method like this in my library

```
public void Foo<T>(IQueryable<T> input)
{
    //T is never used and the code compiles when I remove T
}
```

I want to refactor it and remove the generic parameter.

```
public void Foo(IQueryable input) { ... }
```

How does it affect the code dependent on my library?
Do they need to do a rebuild?
Do they encounter compile error?
What if they have used reflection to call this method?

If I create both of them then the method resolution will always pick the generic one. How can I make the generic one deprecate and obsolete in later versions?

Comment: If you just want to mark it as Obsolete use `[Obsolete]` attribute on your Generic method

Comment: Maybe you should let generic method forward call to nongeneric one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo<T>()` is called `` Foo`1 `` in the compiled code. So it is not the same as `Foo()` that is just called `Foo` in the compiled code.

Based on your question, you have this on a public API and you need backward compatibility. If it was me, I would change it to the following:

```
[Obsolete("Call Foo2() instead of the deprecated Foo()", true)]
public void Foo<T>(IQueryable<T> input)
{
    Foo2(input);
}

public void Foo2(IQueryable input)
{
...
}
```

Anything that is compiled against this new version will complain if it uses the old method. This is true both for inhouse and 3rd party code, that is why I would include the explanation in the error message what to do next.